# Whats the ids amount limitation for YT.videos get by id list API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Trying out [Youtube.Video API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22ebsS9tEi5zc%2C07d2dXHYb94%2CV4LnorVVxfw%2CTOd9iAn9tE0%2CavAqRSZ29wQ%2CdQ5BAupEKvw%2Ca9S8OYemyHQ%2CVUb450Alpps%2CT0CfbTOXMr4%2CRKBcs9tNWg8%2CiPW75ZO4pIA%2CZ24QuAGV2D0%2CX2lIovmNsUY%2CYQDDm9HLkV4%2Cd9fqrXsDvBg%2ClyelxGIydeQ%2CbseyU2PvBQo%2CFu_rLIq7-5o%2CrZVpo5HbDf8%2Co1YA_6tXs5E%2CBkD2nN5275c%2CCgvUney-Vok%2CWR7EBq2dsFk%2CUEJQul_2tds%2C6R8n6FbXVc8%2CUcsQScInoXk%2CagQ23NdBROY%2Cd6kjZXwdyJs%2CBmrBJE-8JE4%2C1hN8PN26OeQ%2CVqnAD_8pna0%2C8r8aYdamaR4%2C5_l4t6p8vCw%2C30vhV57llTA%2CnFrb-C6I6Ps%2CBNETheyse1k%2C3dcli9i_pvA%2CXxOB13gjBcc%2CSotxYVOqR6A%2CFcMRkyoHKeA%2CU5KLMeFK_UY%2Cxf0Mi3kWKhY%2CiZbFFXQ3zIE%2C1HygThMLzGs%2CERTzrGQw3BE%2CfpIPcgQTusc%2CqiaF4kuxJco%2CbzZEH_5OuIs%2CDuwzNC5UvfY%2CF4V3rwGf8Hg%2C6jKrkMTs3YA%2CPTqAs-CBoxE%2CyfUflij74P4%2CPnhxz0learg%2Cimi8YDvyWn0%2CEg86emJjbwk%2CWybG8FesMc8%2CXiCrniLQGYc%2Cozq45cJv7XI%2CQJupEXcoF6o%2C2OBm_4aoXNI%2Cwf3hbZr0Skw%2CXHMEMJK9nic%2C3Pv7jAKIPa0%2CaCv10_WvGxo%2C%22%5D%7D) fails for a list of 100 ids.

The API doesn't say any amount limitation.
How can I tell what's the limitation besides trying one-by-one?

The IDs:

`ebsS9tEi5zc,07d2dXHYb94,V4LnorVVxfw,TOd9iAn9tE0,avAqRSZ29wQ,dQ5BAupEKvw,a9S8OYemyHQ,VUb450Alpps,T0CfbTOXMr4,RKBcs9tNWg8,iPW75ZO4pIA,Z24QuAGV2D0,X2lIovmNsUY,YQDDm9HLkV4,d9fqrXsDvBg,lyelxGIydeQ,bseyU2PvBQo,Fu_rLIq7-5o,rZVpo5HbDf8,o1YA_6tXs5E,BkD2nN5275c,CgvUney-Vok,WR7EBq2dsFk,UEJQul_2tds,6R8n6FbXVc8,UcsQScInoXk,agQ23NdBROY,d6kjZXwdyJs,BmrBJE-8JE4,1hN8PN26OeQ,VqnAD_8pna0,8r8aYdamaR4,5_l4t6p8vCw,30vhV57llTA,nFrb-C6I6Ps,BNETheyse1k,3dcli9i_pvA,XxOB13gjBcc,SotxYVOqR6A,FcMRkyoHKeA,U5KLMeFK_UY,xf0Mi3kWKhY,iZbFFXQ3zIE,1HygThMLzGs,ERTzrGQw3BE,fpIPcgQTusc,qiaF4kuxJco,bzZEH_5OuIs,DuwzNC5UvfY,F4V3rwGf8Hg,6jKrkMTs3YA,PTqAs-CBoxE,yfUflij74P4,Pnhxz0learg,imi8YDvyWn0,Eg86emJjbwk,WybG8FesMc8,XiCrniLQGYc,ozq45cJv7XI,QJupEXcoF6o,2OBm_4aoXNI,wf3hbZr0Skw,XHMEMJK9nic,3Pv7jAKIPa0,aCv10_WvGxo,PW2duKZChA8,ekTnI22maOI,7j0OY3236jw,UylhV7I55us,kHHMWNjp2KQ,M_WBGbVufmc,Xoq10XJDDdQ,c0A1bkF4mKM,pQGgPQA_FR4,3L43EcAefY8,MEFSjBpuh4A,USMJ7REpLUU,mX4Lt466sqM,L3j2_lltzz8,zD9zjetFQXw,TKoCWh2yneM,4QA30qkRYy8,ASxkyQKZE4k,tvvj0xpSXRc,H-zFRGP7MUQ,Kar7z_9RogY,8mzevBJek-0,4ThPL2Uk6xo,NgWC5oEuyjU,2wEs4jsv9gc,T4aX8Uyxo5A,BRMK77NUsyU,5MXWZ0nmrLE,kPYgXvgS6Ww,VufilzHKTqk,IOoqtlA8i2Y,sMeIORMCxtU,jFMA5ggFsXU,olYOijqE2og,wtH-hdOF1uA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all API endpoints that provide back result sets are limiting by design the cardinality of those sets to 50 per call, when using the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint's [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) parameter, you have to limit the size of the constructed comma-separated list to 50.

Indeed it's true that the official docs does not mention this limit as such; but, otherwise, maybe, the Googlers authoring the docs consider this info to be well-known. Also true that many other such magic limiting numbers w.r.t other API endpoints are not documented as well.